# Wait for Kafka consumer in request/reply semantics to initialise offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using a `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` with a shared reply topic (i.e. group.id is `null` and group management is disabled). The initial offset is set to 'latest'.

I am facing the following issue:

1. I manually start the listener container which causes an async operation that gets the metadata for the consumer.
2. I call the `sendAndReceive()` method.
3. The reply message is created before the async operation in the first step returns.
4. The async operation returns and sets the offset to 1 (due to 'latest'), thus the reply message will be ignored.

In order to fix the issue, I need to assert that the offsets are initialized before calling the `sendAndReceive()` method. I have looked for a suitable [Application Event](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#events), but none of them seem to fit.

Is there any way on how to assert that a consumer has completely initialized?

The problem is similar to [Wait for kafka consumer to poll before writing messages to kafka spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754993/wait-for-kafka-consumer-to-poll-before-writing-messages-to-kafka-spring-boot) but the suggested solution doesn't solve it either (unless I misunderstand the proposal, it would just lower the risk but not eliminate it).

Comment: I opened an issue for this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible.

I opened an issue for this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2318

**EDIT**

As a work around you could set `idleEventInterval` and wait for the first `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`.

Comment: I added a possible work around.

Comment: I will test the workaround and it's great that you have already created a MR. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are using 2.8 or later, you might also need to reduce `idleBeforeDataMultiplier` to 1.0 (it defaults to 5.0). When you get the first idle event, you can increase the interval (or set it to `null` to disable future events). If you are using a concurrent container, you will have to change the properties on each child container `parent.getContainers().forEach(cont -> cont.getContainerProperties().set...`.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into Gary Russell's raised issue and it's now been resolved. You can now do something like `replyingKafkaTemplate.waitforAssignment(Duration.ofSeconds(5))`

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/e19e6d4726a6acd52b81820565a22e8020814bda